# "cannot read data property error" when rendering ejs with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" when i try to render results.ejs with data from api. Can anyone show what's wrong with render code? Thanks.

index.js:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

var link = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=thewdb&";
var title = "hababam sinifi";
var year = "";
var plot = "";

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.get("/results", (req, res) => {
    res.render("results.ejs");
});

axios.get(`${link}t=${title}&y=${year}&plot=${plot}`)
    .then((req, res) => {
        // handle success
        const data = res.data;
        res.render("results.ejs", { data: data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(err);
    })
    .then(() => {
        // always executed
    });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started at http://localhost:3000"));
```

results.ejs:

```
<%- include("partials/header.ejs"); %>

<h1>Results</h1>

<%= data %>

<%- include("partials/footer.ejs"); %>
```

Comment: `axios.get(...).then((req, res) => {})` <-- no, the axios promise does not resolve to `req, res`. Remove the `req, `

Comment: when i remove req, use only res ".then(res) => {" i get "TypeError: res.render is not a function" error. (I'm on Colt Steele's course but he uses "response" in his video but it seems its outdated.)

Comment: Your axios call is at the root of your program. It's executed when the server starts, it's not inside a route middleware. In this case, rename `res` to `response` here (and do `data = response.data`), and move your entire axios call inside an `app.get(...)` callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @blex stated in the comments you API call should be inside the route callback, axios call returns an object with the `data` property.

Inside the route callback you have access to `req` and `res` parameters.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

var link = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=thewdb&";
var title = "hababam sinifi";
var year = "";
var plot = "";

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.get("/results", (req, res) => {

   axios.get(`${link}t=${title}&y=${year}&plot=${plot}`)
    .then((apiResponse) => {
        // handle success
        const data = apiResponse.data;
        res.render("results.ejs", { data: data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(err);
    })
    .then(() => {
        // always executed
    });
});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started at http://localhost:3000"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand the difference between response and api response.

Comment: You are welcome! Consider mark the answer as 'accepted' if it was helpful.